Film/series involving a rich/poor divide and a guy and a girl who fall for one another
The guy in it is new to the 'rich' area and is being introduced to the other people who live in the apartments and socialise together.
Can't remember how he meets the girl, but she lives in a room in the poor area and shares with a sick female....possibly older, but not sure.
They all struggle for food, etc, and he tries to help look after the sick female. The male and female fall for each other.
I think there's another man...older maybe...who helps get food and clothes for the poor people.
At the end, lots of people go somewhere else, where an older couple are waiting to lead them to a new land/place. To get there, they have to pass through a cave/dome, but they can never come back. At the edge of it...last minute he/she changes their mind, I think, and they stay behind. Possibly to keep helping others.

In roughly which year did you watch this? And do you recall which channel or channels you might have seen it on?

Getting Logan's Run vibes but it doesn't quite fit.

It is Downsizing with Matt Damon.
In this movie people can pay to be shrunk to a tiny size. The very wealthy live in one area. And all of the staff of the community live in another.

Paul and Audrey decide to undergo the procedure and move to Leisureland, New Mexico, one of the fancier communities for small individuals.

He meets one of of the housekeepers and visits her in the poor part.

The next morning, Paul recognizes one of Dusan's house cleaners as Ngoc Lan Tran, a Vietnamese political activist who was jailed and downsized against her will, escaped in a television box, barely survived being shipped to the United States, and was brought to Leisureland a year ago to have her leg amputated. Wanting to assist Ngoc Lan with her prosthetic leg, Paul goes to her apartment in the slums just outside the walls of Leisureland where the service workers of the community live. Paul had not thought about this part of the small economy, and is shocked by conditions in the slum.

Paul decides to stay behind with the poor people.

As the door of the vault is closing, Paul changes his mind and steps outside. Back in Leisureland, Paul continues to work with Ngoc Lan to serve the people of the slums, deriving contentment from things like bringing dinner to an old man.

Full plot here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downsizing_(film)

That's it....thank you!!

@June while it's often good practice to wait a day or so to accept an answer, if this is definitely the right answer please do accept it. To do that, click the green checkmark near the voting arrows to the left of the answer. Not only does that make it easier for other people to find the answer and for other answerers to avoid wasting time, it helps a lot with some of the site processes. Thanks!!
